# Separate text from FXML File

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is there anyway to separate Node's text from FXML Files? ( Like android )

```
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
```

for instance :

```
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="@string/mnu_file">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sepcify a [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) when loading the fxml. You can use a property from the resource bundle by using `%<key>` in the fxml.

#### FXML

```xml
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="%mnu_file">
```

#### loading code

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("myproperties.properties");
Parent p = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("some.fxml"), new PropertyResourceBundle(is));
```

#### myproperties.properties

```
mnu_file=File
```

See also [*Introduction to FXML: Resource Resolution*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution)

Comment: ResourceBundles are usually created by one of the static methods of ResourceBundle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html
This makes sure you load the correct Properties file for the given Locale.